# Getting error in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my query

```
   Select * into my_db.employee
   From my_db.persons ;
```

I want to copy data from one table into another table but getting error .

Any help would be helpful

Thanks

Comment: You need to post the error. Make it as easy as possible for people to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax in MySQL is `create table as`:

```
create table my_db.employee as
    Select * 
    From my_db.persons ;
```

Your syntax works in SQL Server.

Comment: This is query of SELECT INTO

Comment: does MySQL not support SELECT INTO query?

Comment: @KetanGupta . . . In MySQL, `select into` is used for writing files or setting user-defined variables, but not for creating tables.  That is what `create table as` does.

Comment: What is used for copying data from one table into another

Comment: @KetanGupta . . . `create table as`, which is described in this answer.